# For sites with shared profiles for meta, should the moderator tools deal with both users as one?

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

Occasionally, you come across a random post where all answers *except one* have received a down vote. Moderator wants to rule out foul play, and tries to do an IP cross reference, only to find that the IP data is only for the site they're on at the time, and doesn't include the data from the parent.

For example, On a stack exchange site, you might see an IP history of:

```
xxx.xxx.233.176   262  
xxx.xxx.201.77    209  
xxx.xxx.201.127   155  
xxx.xxx.236.126   117
```

But on meta, for the **same** user:

```
xxx.xxx.233.176   56
xxx.xxx.201.92    38
xxx.xxx.202.153   18
xxx.xxx.202.22    18
```

I believe it would be useful for the IP tools (history and cross reference) to be combined, perhaps with a breakdown as to how much of that activity is on the current site (there might even be scope for linked accounts to show as an additional column)